# Carmichael function and congruence mod $n^2$

Tags: group-theory

Let n=p.q where p and q are odd primes. Let $\lambda(n)$ be the Carmichael function of n. Show that for every $w \in \mathbb{Z}_{n^2}^*$, we have $w^{n.\lambda(n)} \equiv 1 \mod n^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** We have $w^{\lambda(n)}\equiv 1 \pmod{n}$. So 
$$w^{\lambda(n)}=1+tn$$
for some integer $t$.

To calculate $w^{n\lambda(n)}$ modulo $n^2$, expand $(1+tn)^n$ using the Binomial Theorem.